# Spatstat: Is there a way to test for anisotrophy, especially when there is clustering

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

I am looking for a way to quantify the anisotrophy in spatial patterns.  The KMeasure enables the visualisation, and the difference between the max and min values is an approximation of anisotrophy in a way, but I was wondering if there was a way to test significance or model such anisotrophy? Rajala et al. 2017 gives a wonderful overview of several methods, but I can't seem to find them implemented.
Any suggestions gratefully received
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Section 7.9 of [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org) describes methods for detecting and measuring anisotropy that are implemented in the `spatstat` package. They include the sector K-function `Ksector`, the pair orientation distribution function `pairorient`, the anisotropic pair correlation function `Kmeasure` and the anisotropy ratio. These are all derived from the Fry plot `fryplot` described at the beginning of chapter 7.

You mention "Rajala et al 2017" and presumably you mean the article

- T. Rajala, C. Redenbach, A. S"arkk"a, M. Sormani,
  A review on anisotropy analysis of spatial point patterns,
  *Spatial Statistics* **28** (2017) 141-168.

The new methods proposed in this paper are not currently implemented in `spatstat`.

Contact the authors of the article in the first instance if you want R code for their techniques.

Comment: Thank you, thats really useful.  I will read up from the spatstat book.  Very much appreciated.